# html: should I use figure and figcaption for (video) teaser element

Tags: html, markup, w3c, semantic-markup

I have a list of teasers looking like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <article>
        <h1>Title of Video</h1>
        <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
        <p>Something about the video</p>
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <article>
        <h1>Title of Video</h1>
        <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
        <p>Something about the video</p>
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <article>
        <h1>Title of Video</h1>
        <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
        <p>Something about the video</p>
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Should I use `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` instead of `<article>`?

It is my understanding that I should only use these tags if the text directly describes what is seen in the picture and not in the case depicted above.
But maybe I'm wrong ...

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `figure`, as I've always thought `figure` referred more to content that explains or enhances the main article. It wouldn't appear in a document outline, and could conceivably be moved away as a standalone content without making either itself or the main document unusable. It doesn't seem that either of those conditions really applies in this case, but it may depend on the intent of your main document.

Since the teasers aren't standalone content, and can't really be syndicated individually (the videos themselves are the articles, in other words), I'd use `section` rather than `article`.

Comment: "It wouldn't appear in a document outline" <- you sure about that?

Comment: Not sure, but my interpretation is that it doesn't. `figure` is a sectioning root (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-figure-element) which doesn't appear in the main document outline, nor do its subsidiary sectioning element contribute to the main outline.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think that `figure` would be a good choice, because

- you have more than just the main content (i.e., the thumbnail image) and the caption (i.e., the description), namely the title, and
- the `figcaption` would have to annotate the content of the `figure`, which in your case is the thumbnail image, not the video itself, but it doesn’t really make sense to provide a caption for the thumbnail.

But even if `figure` might be appropriate, I think using `article` is the better choice:

- It allows you to use the [`author` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#link-type-author), should you decide to link to the video author (which in itself is a good indicator that `article` is appropriate here: because the content could have a different author than the page author).
- It allows you to use the [`bookmark` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#link-type-bookmark) for the link to the video (again, a sign that `article` is intended for such a case).

If you’ll use the `bookmark` type or not, the `a` should be part of the `article`:

```html
  <article>
    <a href="" rel="bookmark">
      <h1>Title of Video</h1>
      <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
      <p>Something about the video</p>
    </a>
  </article>
```